# why I can still open my image stored in Firebase storage via browser even though it has rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

so I have security rules like this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {

    match /eventPoster/{imageID} {
            allow read: if isSignedIn()
          allow create: if isSignedIn() && isImage() && lessThanNMegabytes(0.5)
        }



        function isSignedIn() {
          return request.auth != null;
        }

        function isBelongTo(userId) {
          return request.auth.uid == userId;
        }

        function lessThanNMegabytes(n) {
            return request.resource.size < n * 1024 * 1024;
        }

        function isImage() {
            return request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
        }
   }

}
```

as you can see, I set only signed in user that can see/read the image. but if I copy and paste the link from my file in storage like below in incognito browser, I still can see my image

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXXXXXX.appspot.com/o/eventPoster%2F0050370e-a226-4a69-a635-ceccce10007c?alt=media&token=44f6d5a4-ff44-4376-3c7b9dfac465

I expect that I can't see the image via the browser, I test it using google chrome. even though my app is for Android and iOS just for testing I use browser. I assume, I am not signed in if I access it via the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you shared there is a download URL. That URL is publicly readable, regardless of security rules. The only way to stop it from working is by revoking its token from the Firebase console.

If you want a file in Firebase Storage to only be accessible in accordance to its security rules, don't generate download URLs for it, or at least don't share the download URL with anyone.

Comment: currently I need that download URL to display that image in my native app. in Android, I am using Glide library to help me to download and cache the image, but I am using that download URL. is there a better way to display that image and also only signed in user that can see the image ?

Comment: just see the documentation, I think I need to use Firebase UI. am I right ?https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui

Comment: The download URL is unguessable (that `token` in there is random and long enough to make it statistically impossible for someone to guess), but gives public access. If you don't want that approach, you can require the user to be signed in and access the data using the other methods of the Storage API. Those can pull down the data into memory, or into  local file on the device, which you can then feed to Glide too. There's no need to use Firebase UI for this.